# Uncaught Type Error: Can not read property latitude

Tags: javascript, html, position

This is part of a function I have written

```
                watchlocation: function() {
            console.log("watchlocation Started");
            if (watchProcess == null) {
                watchProcess = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(locationcheck.handle_geolocation_query_success, locationcheck.handle_errors, {enableHighAccuracy:true});
            }                       
              if(position.coords.latitude == null) {
                  var Lat = '52.5960';
                  console.log("latitude Set Manually");
              }
              else {
                  var Lat = position.coords.latitude;
                  console.log("latitude Set Automatically");                         
              };

              if(position.coords.longitude == null) {
                  var lon = '-1.9110';
                  console.log("longitude Set Manually");
              }
              else {
                  var lon = position.coords.longitude;   
                  console.log("longitude Set Automatically");
              };
              locationcheck.handle_geolocation_query_successalt(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
              console.log("watchlocation Position Passed");  
     },
```

Every time I try and access position.coords.latitude or position.coords.longitude console says its

> 'Uncaught Type Error: Can not read property 'latitude' of undefined' & 'Uncaught Type Error: Can not read property 'longitude' of undefined

The end result of what I am trying to do here is grab the current location through the HTLM5 standard, if that does not work substitute the lat lon global variables.

I suspect its probably down to my methods here as I am still learning the best way to do things as I have been able to access position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude as part of an alert box before now.

TIA

Terran

EDIT
Jörn Berkefelds comment that I had var postion = ""; else where was correct - I removed it and  it resolved the problem.

T

Comment: i might be mistaken but did you define position (and position.coords) anywhere? please provide a complete code snippet... apart from that: the geolocation api is async - you have to use event-handlers to wait for the user's OK and then start parsing the data. that's probably what causes your problems

Comment: Actually I did define position so I've removed that.... I'm also moving the if / elses to the error handling area which is where it should be really.... I'll retest in a bit. Re the async part - yep - aware of that which is why I'm trying to get the code to look at some initial values first as I'm not found a way to hold execution until its ready.

Comment: Yep - that looks like it worked..... thanks for helping me - hopfully it this will help others too..... T

Comment: @TerranBrown I have this problem, by reading your post/comments I cannot tell how you solved it, can you explain